# Providing bucket path to program through command line

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, filepath, google-cloud-ml

My google cloud bucket has two folders **train** and **test** under **gs://MYBucket/demo2/TFRecords/** which contain TFRecords of image embeddings. I pass the url of my bucket to the program as an argument.

In the terminal I type the below to submit the job:

```
$training='gs://MYBucket/demo2/'

$gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--job-dir $JOB_DIR \
--module-name $TRAINER_MODULE \
--package-path $TRAINER_PATH \
--region $REGION \
-- \
--train-files $training
```

Here **training** contains the address to my bucket

**My code** :

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from StringIO import StringIO

BUCKET=None
DATA_DIR = "TFRecords/train/"

~Some code~

def Load_input():
    global BUCKET    

    filenames = [os.path.join(BUCKET+DATA_DIR, "train-0000%d-of-00002.tfrecord" % i) for i in xrange(0, 1)]

    for f in filenames:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
            raise ValueError("Failed to find file: " + f)
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

~Some code~

def main(unused_args):    
  parser.add_argument('--train-files',help='BUCKET path to training data',nargs='+',required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  global BUCKET
  BUCKET = StringIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(args.__dict__['train_files'][0]))

  ~Some other code that internally calls **Load_input()**~
```

The line :

```
filenames = [os.path.join(BUCKET+DATA_DIR, "train-0000%d-of-00002.tfrecord" % i) for i in xrange(0, 1)]
```

throws error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str'

what I have tried :

```
BUCKET = file_io.read_file_to_string(args.train_files[0])
```

but it raises error:

```
raise ValueError("Failed to find file: " + f)
ERROR   2018-03-16 15:57:55 +0530   master-replica-0        
ValueError: Failed to find file: TFRecords/train/train-00000-of-00002.tfrecord
```

**My Question :**
How am I supposed to join BUCKET and DATA_DIR in order to provide the path to the training files correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, `--train-files` is simply a path.

In that case, you simply need to do the following

```
def main(unused_args):    
  parser.add_argument('--train-files',help='BUCKET path to training data',nargs='+',required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  global BUCKET
  BUCKET = args.train_files[0]
```

Also, you'll consider constructing the whole path using `os.path.join`; currently you are constructing parts using `BUCKET+DATA`, instead try:

```
filenames = [os.path.join(BUCKET, DATA_DIR, "train-0000%d-of-00002.tfrecord" % i) for i in xrange(0, 1)]
```

Finally, if at all possible, I recommend avoiding using a global variable for BUCKET as it may end up causing subtle bugs (e.g. if you accidentally use them before they are initialized). Consider passing value around as arguments instead, e.g.

```
def load_input(bucket):
    filenames = [os.path.join(bucket, DATA_DIR, "train-0000%d-of-00002.tfrecord" % i) for i in xrange(0, 1)]
# ...

def main(unused_args):    
  parser.add_argument('--train-files',help='BUCKET path to training data',nargs='+',required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  load_input(bucket=args.train_files[0])
```

(Also, you may find it helpful to use the same name for the command-line argument as the variable name).

Comment: Right, turns out `StringIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(args.__dict__['train_files'][0]))` is required if you want to pass bucket locations to `python` file-readers like `open()` cause they don't understand bucket locations ie `gs://...` Where as for tensorflow file handlers directly passing the bucket address is understood. Should have tried this earlier. So simple, my question appears stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to use the string without StringIO:

```
BUCKET = file_io.read_file_to_string(args.__dict__['train_files'][0])
```

Also, this ought to be the same thing:

```
BUCKET = file_io.read_file_to_string(args.train_files[0])
```

Comment: I tried that earlier since `file_io.read_file_to_string` returns string, but I got `raise ValueError("Failed to find file: " + f)
ERROR 2018-03-16 15:57:55 +0530 master-replica-0  ValueError: Failed to find file: TFRecords/train/train-00000-of-00002.tfrecord`

Comment: What is the correct filename then? Maybe there is a minor error in the construction of the file name.